# Javascript compare two datetimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I need to compare two datetimes. Format of datetimes is: DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss.

Here is my code:

```
expirationDate = someDate;
var now = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss");

if(moment(expirationDate).isBefore(now)){
    console.log("Past");        
} else {
    console.log("Future");
}
```

for this datetimes it work great:

```
Now: 07-12-2017 11:15:09
Expiration date: 07-12-2017 10:14:10
it return Past
```

but for this it doesn't work:

```
Now: 07-12-2017 11:15:03
Expiration date: 15-12-2016 05:59:00
it return Future
```

I've also tried with if (Date.parse(expireDate) < Date.parse(now)) it also doesn't work properly.
Does anyone know where is the problem or is there any other way to compare two datetimes?

Comment: you can use `+expireDate < +now`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the format of the date string.

```
if (moment().isAfter(moment(expirationDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'))) {
  console.log("Past");
} else {
  console.log("Future");
}
```